# Autocomlete effect - mirroring fields motions jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, user-interface, jquery-autocomplete

I have an input over input to create an autocomplete effect.

I have problem with **Looooooooong** when user using keyboard to go left or right - the fields in the bottom doesn't move with the main field on top.

Is there any way to make the fields move together?

This is an image to show what exactly it's look like
[image: example]

Here you can see an example (http://jsfiddle.net/95mbG/)

```
<div>
<input id="main" type="text" />
<input id="autocomplete" type="text" disabled="disabled" />
</div>
```

Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you please give us an example (in jsfiddle or jsbin) of what you have already tried?

Comment: I added an example on jsfiddle where you can easily see the problem, Thanks

Comment: Your example looks good to me. I'm not quite sure what the problem is? Can you please re-explain your problem? Also, what browser are you using (so I can try and reproduce exactly what you're seeing)?

Comment: Ok, I changed the image and fixed my question. I didn't mention that this is happen only with looooooong text. Sorry for this :)